# How to use? ATmega328P Development Board for Arduino UNO R3 Bootloader Project DIY

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]

How to use? ATmega328P Development Board for Arduino UNO R3 Bootloader Project DIY.

Comment: The answer is: you don't use it. Buy a cheap arduino uno clone. This development board does not have a usb-serial chip, therefor it is not possible to upload a sketch to it without extra hardware. It was probably in the description where you bought it, that you need an extra usb-serial module. Instead of buying an extra usb-serial module, you may just as well buy a arduino uno clone.

Comment: Looks like about 1/5th of an Uno with a ZIF socket. The rest, other than the ZIF socket, is pretty pointless. The USB is for power only. To program it you need an external USB UART interface. It doesn't even have a USB-ASP built in like you'd expect from something that looks like that.  Pretty much a pointless heap of junk.

Comment: @Majenko, the 2x3 header is labeled ICSP, so it is a bootloader flasher

Comment: No, that is for plugging a programmer into. like the Uno's icsp header.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of this board is to flash (Arduino) bootloader to Atmega 328 chips. It has not a build in programmer, only a ICSP header to connect the programmer.

So wire it with a programmer and then chip in, ZIF close, burn bootloader, ZIF release, chip out, next chip in, ZIF close, ....

[video](https://youtu.be/Xetz1HKPRUg?t=148)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can program with this device. Treat it as a Genuino Uno and select AVRISPmkII programmer. Used mine several times.